# SQL column taking "0" as value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One is members table with columns member id, member first name, member last name. I have another table guest passes with columns guest pass id, member id and issue date.

I have a list view that will display guest passes details, like member name and issue date. I have two textboxes. Those are for entering member name and issue date.

Member name textbox is auto complete textbox that is working fine.

But the problem is when I am entering the name that is not in member table. At this time it will accept and display a blank field in list view in member name column and member id is stored as "0" in guest pass table.

I don't want to display the member name empty blank and I don't want to store "0" in guest pass table.

This is the insert statement:

```
sql2 = @"INSERT INTO guestpasses(member_Id,guestPass_IssueDate)";
sql2 += " VALUES(";
sql2 += "'" + tbCGuestPassesMemberId.Text + "'";
sql2 += ",'" + tbIssueDate.Text + "'";

guestpassmemberId = memberid
```

Is there any validation that needs to be done? Can anyone give suggestions on this please? This is the auto complete textbox statement:

```
sql = @"SELECT member_Id FROM members WHERE  concat(member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname) ='" + tbMemberName.Text+"'";
dt = GetData(sql, mf);
if (dt != null)
{
   if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
       tbCGuestPassesMemberId.Text  = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]  ["member_Id"]).ToString();
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me on this? Is there any type of validation with SQL query?

Comment: if this question is unclear pls intimate me ...

Comment: Are you basically trying to determine the 'next' `memberID` so it can be displayed? Also, you need to parameterize your Sql.  ;)

Comment: if the member name is not in list it will accepting and displaying the all the details in list view with empty  member name. i don't want this displayed empty one ..... is there any validation that need to be done on auto complete text box .....

Comment: would you pls give a sample code...if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that tbCGuestPassesMemberId.Text is always going to have a value, whether it gets set or not. I would suggest putting the first section of code in an if statement as a hack around this, as I guess your member IDs start at 1 anyway?

```
if (tbCGuestPassesMemberId.Text != 0)
{
  sql2 = @"INSERT INTO guestpasses(member_Id,guestPass_IssueDate)";
  sql2 += " VALUES(";
  sql2 += "'" + tbCGuestPassesMemberId.Text + "'";
  sql2 += ",'" + tbIssueDate.Text + "'";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to supply a value for `memberID` if that is an *auto_increment* field. MySql inserts that number for you. If, on the other hand, you require the value to be displayed **prior** to actually writing that member/guest data to the data store, then there are several ways to achieve that.

Comment: but that is not an auto increment field in guest pass table. member id is foreign key for guest pass table and primary key for member table

Comment: is there any validation that will check the text entered in  auto complete text box with the member name in table called members....

Comment: any one pls help me on this topique